# How to return by order using pagination

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have `findPaginated` method wchich add pagination every 20 records. New records have to be at top, so I added `findAllByOrderByIdDesc();` to my repo and everything works fine without pagination, but I have no clue how can I connect both.

In my `InfoService`

```
public Page<Info> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo -1, pageSize);
        return this.infoRepo.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

I don't know how can I make something like this:  `return this.infoRepo.findAllByOrderByIdDesc(pageable));` ...

In my `InfoController`

```
@GetMapping("/info/list")
    public String showInfo (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("infos", infoRepo.findAllByOrderByIdDesc());
        return findPaginated(1, model);
    }

//...

@GetMapping("info/list/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable(value = "pageNo") int pageNo, Model model) {

        int pageSize = 20;
        Page<Info> page = infoService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize);
        List<Info> infos = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalElements", page.getTotalElements());

        model.addAttribute("infos", infos);
        return "info";
    }
```

This part before changes was working fine

```
@GetMapping("/info/list")
    public String showInfo (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("infos", infoRepo.findAllByOrderByIdDesc());
        return "info";
    }
```

so I added `return findPaginated(1, model);` to make pagination every 20 records and Im stuck, don't know how can I connect it properly to make it work.

Info

```
Entity
public class Info {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add order to a `PageRequest` as follows:

```java
PageRequest.of(pageNo -1, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
```

This way paginated results will be ordered by the "id" field with order direction DESC.

Then use your `infoRepo#findAll` method as usual.

```java
public Page<Info> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo -1, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
        return this.infoRepo.findAll(pageable);
}
```